# Running onEdit script only in certain sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm having an issue with one of my scripts created from a macro. I want to update a filter onEdit but only when a certain sheet ("Invoice") is open. Here's what I have now that works across all sheets. I've tried a few different things in this forum but I haven't gotten anything to work.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D16').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues([''])
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

Add a sheet name test like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'Invoice') {
    return;
  }
  const criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues([''])
    .build();
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
}
```